# bind9 перенаправление доменов на определённый порт

Tags: dns, bind9

Вот конфиг:

```
$TTL    86400
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
              86400 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN  NS  localhost.
        IN      A       10.207.0.3
*       IN      A       10.207.0.3
_https._tcp IN SRV 10 10 443
```

Домены к нему обращаются следующим образом:

```
zone "www.t.biz" { type master; file "/etc/bind/zones/db.dblist"; check-names ignore; };
```

Как сделать, что-бы при переходе на это доменное имя, клиента перенаправляло на
адрес 10.207.0.3 и порт 443?

Comment: после номера порта ещё target надо указать: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/srv.html

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin А как указать что-бы в качестве target использовались указанные в файле доменные имена?

Comment: явно укажите. или placeholder используйте. только вы сначала попробуйте найти http-клиента, который будет делать dns-запросы для получения этой вашей записи. что-то мне подсказывает, что среди популярных такого клиента просто не встретить.